# WPF Designer Binding with Converter throwing Object Reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

My XAML designer shows Object reference not set to instance errors everywhere I'm using one of my converter while binding. After digging a lot I've found that it happens at this particular line because it is not able to find get the value at design time.

```
TransactionViewModel.getInstance()
```

Even when i try to avoid it by checking it is not null, it still throws the object reference error

TransactionViewModel is a singleton class with 'getInstance()' function to get the instance.

This is my convert function as follows

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim FieldName As String = value.ToString
    Dim FieldNum As Integer = Integer.Parse(parameter)

    If TransactionViewModel.getInstance IsNot Nothing Then
        If TransactionViewModel.getInstance._NR IsNot Nothing Then
            If TransactionViewModel.getInstance._NR.ContainsField(FieldNum, FieldName) Then
                Return Visibility.Visible
            Else
                Return Visibility.Hidden
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return Visibility.Visible
End Function
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this it may help you

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    //Code that throws the exception
   //Code that return null
}
```

VB:

```
If Not System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject) Then
        'Code that throws the ex
        'Code that return null
End If
```

Comment: This worked;


`If Not System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject) Then
            'Code that throws the ex
            'Code that return null
        End If`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you too, i am glad i have been able to help